# How to obtain locked records in table

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003, jet

I have an unsplitted database at terminal server with about 15 concurrent users. Some user actions run vba code with both SQL and DAO data manipulations and sometime cause record locked errors.

For debug purpose i want to monitor locked records in some tables.
Is there some easy way to do it?

Comment: I think this could get tedious.. How do you plan to use the information, may I ask? I believe you could create an Error Handler for Error # 3218 and either call some logging function that will write a record with time, etc to a table or do whatever you please.

Comment: There is already Error Handler for Error # 3218 in the code, but i want to see all locked landscape, not only the faulty one record, in order to understand how to avoid conflict.

Comment: If a recordset of any kind is locked, how are you going to avoid conflict? Wat are you going to do with the information that Access isn't already providing? This is a built-in functionality of Access, and why people severely disapprove of having concurrent users without a back end.

Comment: As @Invent-Animate has hinted, the first thing you need to do is split your database and provide a separate copy of the front-end to each user, even if they are on Terminal Server. If more than one concurrent user is opening the same copy of the front-end (or an "unsplit" database) then you *will* get errors and trying to troubleshoot those errors is rather pointless.

Comment: Unfortunately splitting is not possible due to limitation for amount of opened forms( sub forms and comboboxes)

Comment: So, where do we go from here?